# Calculate & Visualize "time to metastasis" in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am quite new to R and I find myself struggling with the following Issue.

I want to create a barplot with 2 bars that visualizes the time to metastasis in a cohort of 100 patients out which 40 developed metastasis.
One bar represents the patients that have received immunotherapy and the 2. bar represents the patients that did not reiceive immunotherapy.

- 100 patients
- 40 developed metastasis over time
- 30 received immunotherapy

I created an excel_file with the following columns:

1. Metastasis (yes = 1, no = 0)
2. time (if a metastasis was found (so 1 in the column before), any number (1,2,3,...)
3. Immunotherapy (yes = 1, no = 0)

Basically, I have to

1. Filter only the patients who developed metastasis (1)
2. Create a barplot:

   - y-axis: TTM (time to metastasis)
   - x-axis: Immunotherapy (1 bar - yes, 1 bar - no)

I'd be thankful for any help,

kind regards

[image]

```
ggplot(data = M1, aes (x = Immunotherapy, y = Time))+ geom_col()
```

Comment: This question is not suited to SO as is. SO questions should be focused on a single programming question each, and usually contain code to show and reproduce a problem, with the desired and current output. This question seems to be seeking for a detailed walkthrough on how to perform several steps of data wrangling and plotting.

Comment: Another tip: if we are studying time-to-event, boxplots don't usually look as informative as kaplan mayer plots...

Comment: Kaplan-Meier might a more productive search term.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Update 2:** See OP question2 in comments:

We could use `facet_wrap`. I added a column with Cancer_Type to `M1`:
The new data:

```
M1 <- structure(list(Metastasis = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), time = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 1, 3, 5, 8, 6, 7, 10, 7, 9, 9, 9, 3, 
2, 5, 9, 4, 9, 6, 8, 1, 6, 9, 6, 10, 6, 6, 4, 7, 6, 10, 5, 5, 
2, 9, 6, 1, 1, 2), Immunotherapy = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Cancer_Type = c("Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", 
"Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", 
"Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", 
"Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", 
"Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", 
"Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", 
"Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", 
"Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", "Lung cancer", 
"Lung cancer", "Lung cancer", "Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", 
"Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", 
"Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", "Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", 
"Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", "Lung cancer", 
"Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", 
"Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", 
"Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", "Lung cancer", "Lung cancer", 
"Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", 
"Lung cancer", "Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", 
"Lung cancer", "Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", 
"Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", 
"Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", 
"Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", 
"Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", 
"Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", "Lung cancer", "Lung cancer", 
"Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", "Colon cancer", "Lung cancer", 
"Lung cancer", "Lung cancer", "Lung cancer", "Colon cancer", 
"Colon cancer", "Lung cancer")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code with `facet_wrap()`

```
M1 %>% 
  mutate(Immunotherapy = factor(as.character(Immunotherapy), labels = c("no", "yes"))) %>% 
  filter(Metastasis >=1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Immunotherapy, y = time, fill = Immunotherapy)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, alpha = 0.8, color = "black") +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2, alpha = 0.5, size = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) +
  labs(x = "Immunotherapy", y = "Time to metastasis (months)") +
  facet_wrap(~Cancer_Type)+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, ceiling(max(M1$time)), by = 2))
```

[image]
**Update 1:** OP question see comments:

**Question 1:**

- The lines above and below the box are the so called **whiskers** of the **box-and-whisker plot**.
- They represent the range of data outside the box.
- The length of the whiskers is typically 1.5 times the IQR.
- Any data points outside the whiskers are considered outliers and are plotted as individual points.

**Question 2:**
I think you mean Immunotherapy and not metastasis:

With this line:  `mutate(Immunotherapy = factor(as.character(Immunotherapy), labels = c("no", "yes")))`

We transform Immunotherapy (0,1) from numeric to factor. A factor variable has levels and labels. So we can assign to the factor Immunotherapy labels like we did in the above line e.g. "no" and "yes". And now is the key moment it is the order of the natural numbers. So 0 is before 1 and therefore "no" (which is in the line above before "yes") and "yes" is 1.

**First answer**
We could do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# create fake data
M1 <- data.frame(
  Metastasis = c(rep(0, 60), rep(1, 40)),
  time = c(rep(0, 60), sample(1:10, 40, replace = TRUE)),
  Immunotherapy = c(rep(0, 70), rep(1, 30))
)



M1 %>% 
  mutate(Immunotherapy = factor(as.character(Immunotherapy), labels = c("no", "yes"))) %>% 
  filter(Metastasis >=1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Immunotherapy, y = time, fill = Immunotherapy)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, alpha = 0.8, color = "black") +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2, alpha = 0.5, size = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) +
  labs(x = "Immunotherapy", y = "Time to metastasis (months)") +
  theme_classic()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, ceiling(max(M1$time)), by = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Firstly I want to thank you for your quick answer, it is much appreciated! 2 quick questions: 1. I suppose the lines above and below the 2 boxplots are the standard deviations ? When you wrote "labels = c("no", "yes")", can you explain me why the function recognizes no as 0 and yes as 1, because I just labeled no metastasis as 0 and metastasis as 1 and it recognises it as no and yes, respectively.

Comment: Got it! Again your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Got it! Again your help is much appreciated! I understand now how you approached the problem, and yes I wanted to say Immunotherapy instead of metastasis, thank you for the correction. I tried to play around with the functions you gave me above and everything works perfectly, I am more than happy! Just one last question if you don't mind :)... If I wanted to apply the same question on different subtypes, what do you suppose I have to add to the function ? For example If I wanted to distinguish between Lung_Cancer and Colon_Cancer. Somethying like "Subtypes$Lung_Cancer ? Kind regards

Comment: I added the new code!